# Creating a Competency Employee records

Tags: training

Not sure if this is even possible,

I want to create a SP site that will allow me to record an employee and when they are trained to add in the name of the training course, when it was taken and when it expires - a person may have 1 - 30 training courses attached to their name.

I would normally try and use Access but not possible - so I have been using a very long excel document where I just keep adding a new row for the person and adding in that new row a new training record for them... any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If this were [su], I would ask why you can't use Access. If you ask about your problem with Access over there, they may be able to help you use Access instead, if you prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Easily doable with 2 lists and a couple views.

List 1:  Training courses

- "Course Name" Single Line of Text

List 2:  Training Records

- "Employee Name" People picker field
- "Course Name" Lookup field to list 1
- "Date of Course" date field
- "Date of expiration" date field

Training By Employee view of List 2:  All items grouped by Employee name.
Expired training view of list 2: Filter view where "Date of Expiration" is past.

If you want to get fancy, you could have other fields that include metadata about the training course, and use a workflow to populate the Date of Expiration automatically.

You could do the course list as a choice field instead of a lookup field, but this structure allows for future scalability.